# Hiding the <thead> based upon the status value in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ejs

My Ejs Code :

```
<div ng-repeat="doc_insp in inspection_status" class="inspec-divider"> 
       <span class="inspec-title">{{doc_insp.insName}}</span>
  <table class="table table-striped ins-table " dir-paginate="doc in doc_insp.locationAspects | itemsPerPage:itemsPerPage " current-page="currentPage">
      <thead  ng-init="check_ins_status(doc)">
          <tr>
              <td colspan="3">{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}. {{doc.aspectname}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <!-- <td colspan="3">{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}. {{doc.aspectname}}</td> -->
              <td>{{statusgrp}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

              <th id="apt" scope="col" width="150">Comments</th>
              <th  id="chal" scope="col" width="150">Recommentations</th>
              <th id="villa" scope="col" width="150">Rectification Status</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="comment in doc.comments" > 
         <td  ng-if="(comment.status_id.indexOf('<%= inspection_id %>'.toString()) != -1 && comment.status=='C') || comment.status=='P' || comment.status=='O' || comment.status=='R' ">{{comment.comment[0]}}</td>
         <td  ng-if="(comment.status_id.indexOf('<%= inspection_id %>'.toString()) != -1 && comment.status=='C') || comment.status=='P' || comment.status=='O' || comment.status=='R' ">{{comment.recommendation}}</td>
         <td  ng-if="(comment.status_id.indexOf('<%= inspection_id %>'.toString()) != -1 && comment.status=='C') || comment.status=='P' || comment.status=='O' || comment.status=='R' ">
          <select  name="status" id="status" class="txt_box sel_box" ng-model="comment.status" ng-change="update_insstatus(comment,doc._id,doc_insp._id,'<%= project_id%>','<%= inspection_id %>')">
              <option  disabled value="">Select Type</option>
              <option  value="O" >Open</option>
              <option  value="P" >Pending</option>
              <option  value="C" >Closed</option>
              <option  value="R" >Rejected</option>

          </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
  </div>
```

I am hiding the comment based upon status value (If it is C it should not visible and if all the comments are C then the aspect name should not be visible)

My angular code :

```
$scope.check_ins_status = function(comment){

if(comment){
    console.log(comment)
    console.log(comment.comments)
    $scope.statusgrp = [];
    angular.forEach(comment.comments, function(value, key){
        console.log(value.status);
        $scope.statusgrp.push(value.status)
      });
console.log($scope.statusgrp); // Here am getting array for each time but in ejs last array only showing 
}       
}
```

How do i hide the  completely based upon the comment.status value

Comment: Do you want to hide the entire `thead`?

Comment: Yes I want to hide entire

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide the entire row then just move the `ng-if` to the `<tr>` element and remove from all of the `<td>`. This would hide the entire row.

If you are trying to hide the `<thead>` then I am not sure why you would want to hide it. I can edit my answer if you want to edit the thead and can give me more insight into what you are trying.

Comment: The reason is am hiding the comment based upon comment.status so if there is no comments are there to visible i have to hide the heading as well as aspect Name .. If there is no aspect have to show then i have to hide the inspect name too

Comment: But It won't hide the headings and aspect name